# Getting the maximum value of element tuple in list of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have this code:

```
vals = [(1,3,5),(2,2,5),(1,2,6)]
max(vals ,key=itemgetter(1))[2]
```

My question is: why does it return 5 instead of 6 ? I need the maximum value of the last element. If I take `max(...)[0]` it gives 2, if I take `max(...)[1]` it gives 3, but if I take `max(...)[2]` it gives 5. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last element, just say so by using the index `-1` in your code. In your code, the `1` picks the second element of each tuple for comparison in `max` and the `2` is unnecessarily hardcoding the knowledge that your tuples have length three.

```
>>> vals = [(1,3,5),(2,2,5),(1,2,6)]
>>> max(vals, key=itemgetter(-1))[-1]
>>> 6
```

Answer (score 2):

By keying with `itemgetter(1)`, you're asking Python to take the maximum tuple **based on the values of the 1th element**.  (1,3,5) has the biggest element in the 1th index (i.e. 3).  Then you access the 2nd index from that tuple (i.e. 5).

To take the maximum value of the last element, use this instead:

```
>>> max([c for a,b,c in vals])
6
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are passing a list instead of a generator to max?

Comment: Not really, either will work. The list comp will probably be faster unless the data is huge.

Comment: I don't know exactly the convention here, but would `for _, _, c in vals` be appropriate to avoid naming unused variables?

Comment: I don't like using the `_` convention, it can interfere with gettext in webapps, and binding this name can unwittingly disable the repl hook for previous value. I don't mind naming throwaway variables, in contexts when there is not a harm to readability.

Answer (score 1):

`key=itemgetter(1)` means that `max` checks the *second* element of the `tuple` to determine which `tuple` is the "max" tuple.

So it picks the first tuple since `3` is higher than `2`, then you pick the last value and you get `5`

If you want `6`, I guess you could do `max(vals ,key=itemgetter(2))[2]`

But you could also get the values of index 2 and perform the max like this:

```
max(map(itemgetter(2),vals))
```

since you're discarding the other values

Answer (score 0):

`x[2]` is the 3 element of tuple on which max should be calculated and `[2]` is the third element of max tuple calculated

```
max(vals ,key=lambda x:x[2])[2]
```

or

```
max(vals ,key=itemgetter(2))[2] # you were using itemgetter(1) which would be second element of the tuple
```